# Remove "Submitted by" on search results

Tags: 7, search

How can I modify the search results on drupal 7 so that the submitted by author and date doesn't appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed the "Custom search " module and it was the easiest way. https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_search

Answer (score 3):

Try below code in your template.php

```
<?php
  function YOURTHEME_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
  $variables['info'] = '';
  }
?>
```

Or create a template file for search results if not there  named "search-result.tpl.php" and add this

```
<li class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
 <h3 class="title"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
   <a href="<?php print $url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
 </h3>
 <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
   <div class="search-snippet-info">
  <?php if ($snippet): ?>
    <p class="search-snippet"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>><?php print $snippet; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($info): ?>
  <p class="search-info"><?php print $info; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</li>
```

and To remove the author, date and comments count remove or comment out the following lines:

```
<?php if ($info): ?>
  <p class="search-info"><?php print $info; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

and in css

```
.search-info {
display: none;
}
```

Taken answer from [this](http://www.whenwhowhere.com/tech-blog/remove-author-and-date-information-search-results-drupal-7) link

Answer (score 2):

You can also completely remove those items instead of just setting display to none, [template_preprocess_search_result](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_search_result/7) function processes variables for [search-result.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search-result.tpl.php/7) . So by modifying the `template_preprocess_search_result` you can limit the varibles sent to `search-result.tpl.php`. It is the function, use the modified version in `template.php`

```
function template_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
    global $language;

    $result = $variables['result'];
    $variables['url'] = check_url($result['link']);
    $variables['title'] = check_plain($result['title']);
    if (isset($result['language']) && $result['language'] != $language->language && $result['language'] != LANGUAGE_NONE) {
        $variables['title_attributes_array']['xml:lang'] = $result['language'];
        $variables['content_attributes_array']['xml:lang'] = $result['language'];
    }

    $info = array();
    if (!empty($result['module'])) {
        $info['module'] = check_plain($result['module']);
    }

    if (!empty($result['user'])) {
        $info['user'] = $result['user'];
    }
    if (!empty($result['date'])) {
        $info['date'] = format_date($result['date'], 'short');
    }

    if (isset($result['extra']) && is_array($result['extra'])) {
        $info = array_merge($info, $result['extra']);
    }
    // Check for existence. User search does not include snippets.
    $variables['snippet'] = isset($result['snippet']) ? $result['snippet'] : '';
    // Provide separated and grouped meta information..
    $variables['info_split'] = $info;
    $variables['info'] = implode(' - ', $info);
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'search_result__' . $variables['module'];
}
```

by removing the `if (!empty($result['user'])) {` and `if (!empty($result['date'])) {` lines the user and date will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can theme it, change code as you wish, place following code in template.php in your theme root folder.

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
```

$vars['submitted'] = t('Author: !username, created: !datetime', 
    array('!username' => $vars['name'], 
      '!datetime' => format_date($vars['node']->created, 
        'custom', 'M d, Y')));
}