# How to remove "Submitted By" data from google search engines in drupal7?

Tags: 7, theming, search

How can I prevent showing of `Submitted by username` information on google search result pages.

I looked into some of the answers but I am not sure those solutions will remove from google search. I am thinking those are related to drupal search engines.

Here are the links:

[Remove "Submitted by" on search results](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/152149/remove-submitted-by-on-search-results)

https://www.drupal.org/node/1101554

Please help me regarding this. It will be more appreciated if solution will workout for already created data/nodes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the content to show up in Google search, you have a couple options.

1. Hide the "Submitted by" in Drupal itself.  You can do this by going to the content type edit page and unchecking the box for "Display author information."
2. Use a theme template for the content types and move the "Submitted by" information to the bottom of the content. If it is shown at the bottom instead of the top, Google is unlikely to use that information in its search results, since it gives information toward the top higher priority.

What you shouldn't try to do is show information to users but somehow hide it from Google.  This is likely to make Google mad and if they detect it, your site will be penalized.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestions and I accepted this. I have some queries also. As you mentioned to put the "Submitted by" info bottom of the template file, is that the only way i have or Is there a way to not to show that info at all by removing from template file?

Comment: @Suraj You can remove it in the template file, but you can also remove it from the Drupal interface-- it's just a checkbox on the content type edit page, as described in 1. of my answer.

Comment: Yeah i saw that, but my case is like it should get remove from already created nodes also. AFAIK, if I uncheck this option in drupal interface it will applicable only to nodes which are created after disabling this functionality. Thatsy i just asked. :)

Comment: @Suraj What do you mean "AFAIK"? You can just uncheck the box and see what happens...

Comment: AFAIK means As Far As I Know. Okay I will try that only.Thanks.

Comment: @Suraj I meant that you need to try things yourself and ask here when they don't work.  Don't just ask people to help you without trying what has already been suggested.